# How to convert object to array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object :

```
{
   firstName: false,
   lastName: false,
   email: false,
   phone: false,
   accountNumber: false
}
```

How can I convert to array like this? :

```
[
  {firstName: false},
  {lastName: false},
  {email:'false'},
  {phone: false},
  {accountNumber: false}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to do this would be via [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let obj = { firstName: false, lastName: false, email: false, phone: false, accountNumber: false }

let result = Object.keys(obj).map(k => ({ [k]: obj[k] }))

console.log(result)
```

You could also use `Object.entries` as well with `Array.map`:

```js
let obj = { firstName: false, lastName: false, email: false, phone: false, accountNumber: false }

let result = Object.entries(obj).map(([k,v]) => ({ [k]: v }))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: You are welcome. If this helped you solve your problem consider checking the answer s others can find it easier.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ar = Object.entries({ firstName: false, lastName: false, email: false, phone: false, accountNumber: false });
console.log(ar);
```

Comment: Object.entries create from key and value another array. I thinking how to create object in array

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
  firstName: false,
  lastName: false,
  email: false,
  phone: false,
  accountNumber: false
}

console.log(Object.entries(obj));
```

Try this Hope it will Help

Comment: Please explain how this would be different from the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
const obj = {
  firstName: false,
  lastName: false,
  email: false,
  phone: false,
  accountNumber: false
};

const arr = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
  return { [key]: obj[key] };
});

console.log(arr);
```